# Surgery Procedure for Installing a Cybernetic Vocal Cord

Tags: medicine, cybernetics, cyborg

It’s your favourite grenade hugging (soon to be cyborg) buddy Joel. Who is back on the cutting room table today for some new and (unwilling) invasive surgery. You see when Joel was taking a stroll around his home town (in the middle of a war zone). Were he met and became best buds with a live grenade. He got very damaged to the face, neck and lost both eyes. Luckily (or unluckily if you ask Joel) A black site operative was in the area collecting (unwilling) test subjects for some cybernetic experiments and chanced upon him.

Joel was rushed into Surgery and was a pain just to keep alive. When he was finally stabilized the nice doctors began to work on improving Joel for the better.

Unlike his eyes that were replaced, see here for more details and a better understanding on the story: [Procedure for bionic eye surgery](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/125846/procedure-for-bionic-eye-surgery) I don't have a clue on how they would install a new vocal cord system to replace the old one that was heavily damaged. Because the vocal cord is so detailed I have had trouble understanding how the surgery should be done. Perhaps they install the new vocal cord and graft new muscle and attach it to the rest of the neck (but I’m very open on new ideas). This is also made more difficult because they are playing around with his wind pipe so I think they would attach a breathing device just past his neck to keep him alive (but tell me if I'm wrong).

All I can say is the doctors would like to improve on what was replaced. So I was thinking that the new vocal cord can be used to change the voice of the user on command, not so much as a mimic but maybe with time and training. so I'm having a hard time picking between a more natural replacement that can change its structure to make it more easier for the user to mimic; or have a more robotic one that just changes the tone of voice like a setting.

**So my question is this: What would be the Procedure for Cybernetic Vocal Cord Surgery?**

Just to be clear I know about the hand held Electro larynx device. But I’m not to sure if installing a device like that would will work as well, then just replacing the whole thing because the vocal cords are heavily damaged (with parts even missing, i did say it was pain to him keep alive). The device that is installed into the neck should not make his voice sound off (he is a combat cyborg but still needs to blend in).

**The time period is a hundred years in the future with an advanced tech level**

Answer (score 7):

A way that would work is to **remove the damaged larynx and transplant in a new one**.  This has been successfully done.

> When Heidler underwent the transplant 11 years ago, doctors didn't
>   know if he would be able to talk or swallow afterward. They didn't
>   know if the thyroid gland they transplanted along with the larynx
>   would work. They didn't even know if Heidler would live through the
>   surgery.
>
> Of course he did.
>
> And ever since, he has been interviewed on radio and TV, spoken at
>   medical conferences, talked to nurses and laryngectomy patients,
>   trying to explain how the surgery helped him and how it could help
>   others in the future.

http://blog.cleveland.com/metro/2009/06/tim_heidler_worlds_first_laryn.html

He sounds pretty good, too.  Hear him here.
https://youtu.be/5j2tQPhOHGc?t=472

The nice thing about a biological structure is that it maintains itself.  Once the general idea is down (damaged old one out as a laryngectomy, new one implanted, hook up the vessels and away you go) you can SF it up as you see fit.  Have the new structure be vatgrown, or harvested from an alien.   Or semisynthetic and capable of amazing feats of vibrato screaming.  That can comes in handy because your hero has always wanted to head up an Iron Maiden homage band and now he can.